# background and background-position in inherited elements

Tags: css, background, background-position

I have many elements of type **span**, I would like that every element has the same background image, but different position of start of this background image.

HTML

```
<span class="a1"></span>
<span class="a2"></span>
```

This CSS works (JSFiddle example: http://jsfiddle.net/knxag5fy):

```
span {display: inline-block}
.a1 {background: url('back.png') no-repeat; background-position: -12px -2px; width: 9px; height: 10px}
.a2 {background: url('back.png') no-repeat; background-position: -8px -14px; width: 9px; height: 15px}
```

I would like to short this in that way (JSFiddle example: http://jsfiddle.net/x48jjumm):

```
span {display: inline-block; background: url('back.png') no-repeat}
.a1 {background-position: -12px -2px; width: 9px; height: 10px}
.a2 {background-position: -8px -14px; width: 9px; height: 15px}
```

But this way doesn't work (**background-position** has no effect). How can I fix it please?

Comment: jsfiddle example please.

Comment: @user3102393 your second fiddle has almost same background-position(-2px for x and -14px for y) for a2 as a1. If you increase that, it will work.[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/anpsmn/x48jjumm/1/)

Comment: I also run into it everytime. Looks like only having all the background properties under a single block of CSS works.